# Can not append option element dynamically using Jquery/Javascript and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue. I am trying to append option tag dynamically but its not coming properly using Jquery/Javascript.Here also I am using bootstrap `chosen-select` class. I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="popover-content">
<p>                            
<select class="chosen-select text-left" style="width:100%;" id="ctid">
<option value="" selected>Select City</option>
</select>
</p>
</div>
```

My javascript code is given below.

```
var url="common.php?action=getCity";
$.post(url,{"con_data":conval.options[conval.selectedIndex].value},function(data){
    var obj=JSON.parse(data);
    if(obj.isData==1){
        $('#ctid').find('option').not(':first').remove();
        $.each(obj.cid, function() {
    $("#ctid").append("<option value="+this.city_id+">"+this.city_name+"</option>");
        })
    }
})
```

Here also i am getting the data properly and the loop is also running.But its not reflecting at front end.when I did inspect element i got the below generated html code.

```
<div class="popover-content">
<p>                            
<select class="chosen-select text-left" style="width: 100%; display: none;" id="ctid">
<option value="" selected="">Select City</option>
<option value="18">Bhubaneswar</option>
<option value="17">Delhi</option>
<option value="16">Bangalore</option>
<option value="15">Mumbai</option>
</select>
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-with-drop chosen-container-active" style="width: 0px;" title="" id="ctid_chosen">
<a class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1"><span>Select City</span>
<div><b></b>
</div>
</a>
<div class="chosen-drop">
<div class="chosen-search">
<input type="text" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<ul class="chosen-results">
<li class="active-result result-selected" data-option-array-index="0">Select City</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</p>
</div>
```

The raw html code is generating the above part after option added dynamically.But my problem is thosze are not display on the front end view.Please help me to resolve thisz issue.

Comment: what are you contents of variable `data`?

Comment: check my post all data are already append inside option tag but its not displaying.Please check my generated html outut in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think each loop every object and gives index as its first param and val as second, try this:

```
$.each(obj.cid, function(idx, o) {
  $("#ctid").append("<option value="+o.city_id+">"+o.city_name+"</option>");
});
```

If you would like to get the options in the resulting ul, then make sure to append them first before initing chosen.

```
$.each(obj, function(idx, o) {
  $("#ctid").append("<option value=" + o.city_id + ">" + o.city_name + "</option>");
});

$('#ctid').addClass('chosen-select');
$('.chosen-select').chosen();
```

HTML

```
<div class="popover-content">
  <p>                            
    <select class="text-left" style="width:100%;" id="ctid">
      <option value="" selected>Select City</option>
    </select>
  </p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: No,I did as per you but same issue. Please check my generated output html in my post.

Comment: @subhra I dont get it, what is not displayed?

Comment: Am I doing something different? [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frankcamara/8dt8L5mj/)

Comment: those binding datas in drop down list.It will display while `<li class="active-result result-selected" data-option-array-index="0">Select City</li>` list will complete like option because here one class `chosen-select` is using from bootstrap and its generating all extra stuffs.Please check my post again.

Comment: Let me to clear again. First section code from my post is the original html code but its generating the output which are given last section in my post due to class `chosen-select` from bootstrap. SO it is something different than normal code like ur code.

Comment: it helped me a lot.Thank you.